# R: group by list of column names

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have a data table which is a result from a join between 2 other tables (a, b)

```
joinedTable   = a[b, on = columnName]
```

I want to count the frequency of rows combinations based con column names which can vary (all, one on somewhere in the middle). The problem is it works being hardcoded but not with a variable:

```
joinedTable[, list(freq =.N), by = list( COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, ...)] # works

# what's next doesn't
columns = names(joinedTable)[-which(names(joinedTable) %in% c('COLUMN_F', 'COLUMN_G',...))]
    joinedTable[, list(freq =.N), by = as.list(columns)] # doesn't work
```

If I try to do it dynamic I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(joinedTable, , list(freq = .N), by = list(outColumns)) : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (13). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (23).
```

How should it be so that it works?

Comment: This question is not off-topic. I am clearly asking how to solve a programming issue.

Comment: Have you gone through the Getting Started wiki? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the answer and it's pretty simple and silly the error:

this line

```
joinedTable[, list(freq =.N), by = as.list(columns)]
```

needs to be changed to:

```
joinedTable[, list(freq =.N), by = columns]
```

since columns is already an array.

Comment: Note that within `[ ]` of data.table objects, you can use `.()` to represent a list, so that, you could also write this as `joinedTable[, .(freq =.N), by = columns]`. Maybe a little more concise.

Comment: There are many options for specifying `by`. See `?data.table`.